# How Ergodic is the Irrational Rotation Dynamics?

Tags: real-analysis, dynamical-systems

Let $x$ be any irrational number and $\{.\}$ denote the decimal part of a number. Then is it the case that
$$\inf_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\,\,n\{nx\} =0 $$
In other words, does it hold that for any positive $\varepsilon$, there are infinitely many positive integers like $n$ such that
$$|\{nx\}|\leq\frac{\varepsilon}{n}$$

Of course, Dirichlet's approximation theorem immediately implies that this is the case for $\varepsilon\geq1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick answer is no.

Recall every rational approximation $\frac{m}n$ to the golden ratio $\varphi=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2$ satisfies
$$
\left\lvert\frac{m}n-\varphi\right\rvert\geq\frac1{Kn^2}
$$
(see, for example, Jyrki's answer [here](/a/1257130)).  Hence
$$
\lvert n\{n\varphi\}\rvert\geq\frac1K.
$$

Comment: I hate this fact, but thank you very much for the quick response! Do you also know if there is a $K$ for any other irrational number as well?

Comment: @K.Sadri This will apply to any irrational number whose simple continued fraction expansion has bounded elements.

Comment: I don't understand the answer. If I understand correctly, it holds that $n\varphi = \lfloor n\varphi\rfloor + \{n\varphi\}$. Hence, the inequality is$$\frac 1K\le |mn - n^2\varphi| = |mn - n(\lfloor n\varphi\rfloor + \{n\varphi\})| = |n(m - \lfloor n\varphi\rfloor) - n\{n\varphi\}|.$$How does that imply that $n\{n\varphi\}$ can't be as small as you want?

Comment: @amsmath Notice that this holds for any rational approximation $\frac{m}{n}$, so $m$ is arbitrary. In particular, it holds for $m = \lfloor n\varphi \rfloor$, which gives the desired inequality.

Comment: @AmadeusMaldonado Oh dear, my brain... Thanks for clearing this up.